# Noise Removal using Lucene 4.8

Tags: lucene, noise

I couldn't find any examples of removing stop-words from text using Lucene 4.8. Can you please advise me on how to use the classes StopFilter and StopAnalyzer classes to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Two of three `StandardAnalyzer` constructors allow specifying stopwords; just use any of those. This analyzer uses `StopFilter` underneath, you don't have to do anything extra.

Comment: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/searching-made-easy-with-apache-lucene-4-3.html

Comment: That doesn't help me. It doesn't have any stop word removal code.

Comment: Please re-read my answer. The example code in the link uses `StandardAnalyzer` which can be configured with stopwords.